# Update DataGridView Checked Record to the Database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

So I have this `DataGridView` on which there are two columns which I am retrieving from my `SQL Server` database. Now, in the second column, we have a bit field which shows as a CheckBox in my Windows Application designer. So, I want to, on `CellContentClick` event be able to update the value that just got deselected into my database. But seems like I am going nowhere.

Here is my code below:

```
 private void gvTurnOffNotifications_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
         foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gvTurnOffNotifications.Rows)
         {
             DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
             //We don't want a null exception!
             if (cell.Value != null)
             {
                 bool result = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[1].Value);
                 if (result == true)
                 {
                     //It's checked!
                     btnUpdateTurnOff.Enabled = true;
                     myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                     using (mySQLConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
                     {
                         int temp = 1;
                         bool change = false;

                         string procedureName = "update UsersNotified Set AllowNotification='" + change + "' where AllowNotification='" + false+ "'";
                         mySQLCommand = new SqlCommand(procedureName, mySQLConnection);
                         mySQLCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                         mySQLCommand.Connection = mySQLConnection;
                         mySQLCommand.Connection.Open();
                         mySQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

And then when I click on my "Update" button, I want to send the updated griddata for storing in my database as below:

```
 private void btnUpdateTurnOff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (mySQLConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
            {
                mySQLDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("spGetAllUpdatedNotifications", mySQLConnection);
                mySQLDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                mySQLCommand.Connection = mySQLConnection;
                mySQLCommand.Connection.Open();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                mySQLDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                mySQLDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = mySQLCommand;
                mySQLDataAdapter.Update(ds);
            }
        }
```

The `spGetAllUpdatedNotifications` object in my Update block is a stored procedure I am calling just to retrieve the records from the database so I can update them on the fly in my `DataSet`. Here is the definition below:

```
create proc spGetAllUpdatedNotifications
as
begin
SELECT UserName, AllowNotification FROM UsersNotified where AllowNotification=1
  end   
GO
```

For more context: When my form loads, I am selecting all the records from the database which have their AllowNotification field set to bit 1 (true in C#) and once a user unticks a specific user (in other words, that user would not be allowed to receive notifications anymore) and once I click on the Update button, it should set the property to false (bit 0 in the database).

Instead of updating the one record which I have deselected, it updates all of them. "All" in this case are the records which have `AllowNotification=1`. I only want to set `AllowNotification=0` for the deselected/unchecked record **only**

Any suggestions on how I can go about achieving this?

Comment: What problem you are facing with current code?

Comment: Instead of updating the one record which I have deselected, it updates all of  them. "All" in this case are the records which have `AllowNotification=1`. I only want to set AllowNotification=0` for the deselected/unchecked record only.

Comment: Coz you don't have where clause in update query.

Comment: It is there. Please check again. Its just that the `where` clause is wrong. That's where the issue is. It's a logic error which I just can't wrap my head around

Comment: Your where clause is not correct. As per your query all the rows with `AllowNotification=false` will be updated to true. You need a condition in where clause which can identify the single record which you want to update such as userid or something.

Comment: How will the UserId be mapped to the record that just got deselected? That's what I'm battling with

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147812/discussion-between-chetan-ranpariya-and-harold-finch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what logic makes you to loop thru all the rows of the DataGridView just to update one row in the database.

If you want to update `AllowNotification` value for the username for which checkbox is checked or unchecked the logic would be this.

1. Figure out the updated value of the checkbox which is clicked in the gridview.
2. Store the updated value (True or False) in a boolean variable.
3. Retrieve the corresponding username of from the other cell of the same row the gridview.
4. Execute update query with criteria "WHERE UserName = {userName}".

You need to write CellContentClick event of the DataGridView as following.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) //Assuming Checkbox is displayed in 2nd column.
    {
        this.dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);

        var result = this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
        var userName = this.dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value; //Assumin username is displayed in fist column

        var connectionString = "Your Connection String";
        //Set value of your own connection string above.

        var sqlQuery = "UPDATE UsersNotified SET AllowNotification = @allowNotification WHERE UserName = @userName";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@allowNotification", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = result;
                command.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = userName;
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should help you resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a **partial** solution (It doesn't work a 100% but at least its a step in the right direction):

```
 private void gvTurnOffNotifications_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (gvTurnOffNotifications.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            {
                int selectedrowindex = gvTurnOffNotifications.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

                DataGridViewRow selectedRow = gvTurnOffNotifications.Rows[selectedrowindex];

                getUserSelected = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["UserName"].Value);

                MessageBox.Show(getUserSelected);

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gvTurnOffNotifications.Rows)
                {
                    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

                    //We don't want a null exception!
                    if (cell.Value != null)
                    {
                        //It's checked!
                        btnUpdateTurnOff.Enabled = true;
                        myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FSK_ServiceMonitor_Users_Management.Properties.Settings.FSK_ServiceMonitorConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                        using (mySQLConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
                        {
                            bool change = false;

                            string procedureName = "update UsersNotified Set AllowNotification='" + change + "' where UserName='" + getUserSelected + "'";
                            //MessageBox.Show(cell.Value.ToString());
                            mySQLCommand = new SqlCommand(procedureName, mySQLConnection);
                            mySQLCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            mySQLCommand.Connection = mySQLConnection;
                            mySQLCommand.Connection.Open();
                            mySQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Problem is that it just takes the first row without me having selected the row I want to deselect.